# How to stress test a built c# program (program.exe) that spins a thread by launching multiple instances

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple C# console program that spins a thread and runs a function for example:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    Thread t = new Thread( NewThread );
    t.Start();
}

static void NewThread()
{
    Console.WriteLine("some complex parsing....");
}
```

Now I want to test so that I can run multiple instances of `program.exe`. I am assuming this will be like emulating running multiple threads at the same time since my program start one new thread. I am new to threading just trying to wrap my head around how to stress test this simple program.

Edit: its a console command line application I will be passing in different length files varying from 100 lines to 10000 or more.

Comment: My advise is to never try learning Multitasking or Multithreading in Console Applications. You have to deal with extra issues, like keeping the programm alive and responsive. GUI's deal with that part directly. | It is also unclear what *part* of the programm you want to stress test.

Comment: Unlike Christopher, I don't see a problem to do multitasking or multithreading in a console app. However I agree: it's not clear what is stress test here, and what part needs to be stress tested; furthermore, there should be at least one parameter on which we act to do the stress testing of your program, and another parameter as a criterion.

Comment: sorry for confusion for using the word stress test...I just want to see how the performance will vary when multiple instances of the program are launched.. its a console command line application I will be passing in different length files varying form 100 lines to 10000 or more I hope that clarifies the intent.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you just want something that processes an arbitrary number of files efficiently in parallel. Multithreading is quite complicated (for example how to determine the efficient amount of threads to use for your parallel work), and I advise you not to re-invent the wheel. Take a look at the `Parallel.ForEach` functionality of dotnet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop. Seems like it could really work for you

Comment: @Knoop Yeah i can look into that, but i am not sure if that will solve the problem though because i want to run the program in different terminals with different set of parameters like for example devicename and then filename..at the same time, isn't Parallel.forEach more like running one instance and passing multiple files.

Comment: Yeah the `Parallel.ForEach` is indeed for within 1 instance of your application. So if you want to run the application a lot of times that doesn't help.

Comment: You are only stressing the machine, not your program.  Whatever you'll measure will reproduce poorly on an arbitrary other machine you know nothing about.